# Resin server error "500 Servlet Exception", seems to have some error on jdk or something

Tags: jsp, resin

I'm suffering from opening jsp page on resin server. It actually didn't work on jetty too, but I moved to resin after my prof told me that jsp would work better on resin.

I installed jdk version 1.8.0_65 and set the directory in environment variables. index.jsp is in webapps/ROOT, nothing is in WEB-INF/classes folder.

The error message I got when I opened .jsp file is as follows:

```
500 Servlet Exception

javac compiler is not available in Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_65-b17.
Check that you are using the JDK, not the JRE.
Resin/4.0.44 Server: 'app-0'
```

and also I set the environment variables as follows.

> JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
>
> Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\lib\tools.jar

Path has some more but but they don't seem to be related to this issue.

Comment: in addition, all the directories are correct. no Program files(x86) or something.. i installed jdk1.8 after deleting 1.7.

Comment: try copying `tools.jar` into resin's lib folder (not the best of solutions but might do the trick). And restart server

Comment: @MaVRoSCy , This isn't help. You have to downgrade JDK from 64bit to 32bit. I have did downgrade from 64bit to 32bit, and it seems working like charm!

Answer (score 0):

The space in "Program Files" cause issue sometimes, better to use the short forms for the same,

for "Program Files"  use "Progra~1"
for "Program Files(x86)" use "Progra~2".

I have faced the same error while working with Resin server.
However I have did much R&D, and come to the conclusion that Resin configuration trying to find 32bit JDK, if you have installed JDK64 bit then you definitely face the same error (You need to configure the Resin to find the JVM 64 bit using ). If you remove 64bit JDK and install 32bit JDK then you will not face the same error again.

Thanks!!!